# Add Powershell as Administrator to Explorer Context

Tags: windows, powershell, context-menu

Presently I have run [Command Prompt as Admin](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/47415-open-command-window-here-administrator.html) in my context menu.
I would like to have similar functionality for `Powershell as Admin`.

Can any one guide me, how do I achieve that?

Simply I tried to change `cmd.exe` with `powershell.exe` and change context name. It didn't work. It replaced existing `Command Prompt` and opened non-usable `Powershell`

Comment: See this..http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/06/25/pstip-how-to-start-an-elevated-powershell-from-windows-explorer/

Comment: @Moab, that's great. The only problem is `it replaces existing cmd prompt as admin` shortcut in context menu. I would like to have both

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE, Please re-read my question. If I am not able to convey it rightly, let me know. It's not the problem of running PS as admin. It's about adding a context shortcut in Explorer.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE, boss read the question. `Shortcut in Explorer Context menu` do you understand what that means?

Comment: @Reddy add the fact you want both, to your question as it is not clear that is your intention.

Answer (score 1):

You may install alternative terminal [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/) (I'm the author) where you may run any shell you want. Than, creating any context menu becomes as simple as few clicks.

[Settings/Integration](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsIntegration.html)

- ConEmu here groupbox
- Menu item: `PowerShell (admin)`
- Command: `PowerShell -cur_console:a`
- Icon file: `PowerShell.exe`

Don't forget to press `Register` button.